# For each checkIn on VSTeam automatically build and publish website to FTP server

Tags: .net, visual-studio, azure-devops, web-deployment, azure-pipelines

For each check-in I want to build my application and publish to a FTP server (remote server). Mmy source control is Visual Studio Team Services.

I created a build definition, for each check-in it is creating a build.

I'd like to setup the next step, which is to publish my build results to my FTP server, but do not know how to proceed.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple solutions to your problem. The simplest is to use [the Curl task](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/vs/alm/build/steps/utility/curl-upload-files). there are some issues with the curl task when uploadign a massive amount of files though.

A few VSTS Extensions solve this issue, but you'd need to install them to your account:

- [FTP Uploader](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=januskamphansen.ftpupload-task)

You can also configure [Web Deployment](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd434211(v=vs.100).aspx) and use one of the Web Deploy/MsDeploy tasks to publish them to your target environment:

- [MSDeployAllTheThings](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rschiefer.MSDeployAllTheThings)